# Changing the nested resource helper conventions in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a resource that was previously not nested and now needs to be nested. As a result I'm completely uninterested in rails default conventions of naming it's url helpers `parent_child_path` and having to refactor all of the resource path references.

Is there a way override this convention and get the nested resource to use just `child_path` as the conventions instead.

Comment: have you got any problem with it, i think its good it shows other person who works on project that this resource is nested

Comment: No I don't really like it, but I mainly don't want to go through refactoring for something like this. I'm not sure why that would be important when referencing it from a helper. As far as I'm concerned all that matters is the resource name being referenced.

Answer (score 0):

```
resources :parents, :shallow => true do
  resources :children
end
```

Will allow `parent_child_path` and `child_parent_path` (shallow)

If you still want to access `child_path` just add it as non-nested resource

```
resources :children

resources :parents, :shallow => true do
  resources :children
end
```

Comment: I don't think that's exactly what I want. I still want the URI structure of /parent/:id/child/:id but I don't want to have to change all of my URL helpers for the child just because I've nested it.

Comment: `child_path` will be `/child/:id` If you want `/parent/:id/child/:id` to be matched for `/child/:id` how are you going to determine the parent? (Unless you do that on hitting the method if its a has_one relationship)

Comment: There is only one resource of this type name. I merely want to change the name of it's helper method. It's nothing special, there is no need to determine anything here.